# Can I delete old/unused bookmarks in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, speed, bookmarks

I have bookmarks dating back to probably 2009 or so, from when I was using Firefox up until now. 6 years of bookmarks seems to slow down my address bar as Chrome seems to search through them every time I type to make a suggestion. I like the suggestion feature, but I don't like how it takes up to 10 seconds for Chrome to recognize my keyboard strokes, and we're talking new hardware here.

So beyond Google optimizing the address bar with more aggressive caching, my question is, is there a way to delete old/unused bookmarks in Google Chrome? I see how I can delete all bookmarks or chunks of bookmarks, but not necessarily just the ones I no longer use. Figured there would be an add-on for this but I haven't found one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If the bookmark is in the bookmarks bar, highlight with the cursor/arrow, right click and scroll down to Delete command, left click to delete, then confirm. Or, in the Customize and Control Google Chrome menu (3 short horizontal bars near upper right corner of window), left click, scroll down to Bookmarks, find the one you want to delete, right click and scroll down to Delete command, left click to delete, then confirm. In the latter case, look for a folder marked Imported from Firefox. If you think the offending bookmarks date back to your use of that browser, you may find them most easily in that folder. Good hunting!

Comment: I'm looking to delete unused bookmarks, ones I haven't clicked on in over a year. What you described is how to manually delete bookmarks.

Comment: This is the classic kind of answer you get from people who often have "10,000 answers!" in their profile. They never read the actual question and never answer it. They just latch on to one or two words from your question and answer that instead.